# Evaluate $\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx$

Tags: calculus

> Assume $f(x) = 0$ when $x$ is irrational and $f(m/n) = 1/n$ where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers with $m>0$. Show $f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$ and evaluate $\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx$.

This is integrating the raindrop function except at $x = 0$. I think a good idea here would be to use the lower and upper integrals. That is $\displaystyle \overline{\int_{0}^1} f(x) dx \geq \int_{0}^1 f(x) dx \geq \underline{\int_{0}^1} f(x) dx$. Looking at the raindrop function seems to suggest that the lower integral will be $0$ and so to show the function is integrable we need to show that the lower and upper integrals are equal.

[image]

Comment: Given an $\epsilon >0$, find a partition such that the difference between the lower sum and the upper sum over that partition is less than $\epsilon$. Alternatively, show that $f$ is continuous at all irrationals, and apply the characterisation of Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: The lower integral must be zero since in every interval there is an irrational number.

Comment: Can't we conclude that the function is integrable since its area is less than or equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and greater than $0$?

Answer (score 1):

For all $\epsilon$, choose the size of the partition to be $\delta$, then
$$\overline{\int_0^1}f(x)dx\le\frac{1}{1}\delta+\frac{1}{2}\times2\delta+\frac{1}{3}\times 3\delta+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\times n\delta+\frac{1}{n+1}\times 1=n\delta+\frac{1}{n+1}$$.

If you choose $n$ s.t.

$$\delta>\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$.

This we have
$$\overline{\int_0^1}f(x)dx \le 2n\delta$$

Choose $\delta=\epsilon/2n$. then
$$\overline{\int_0^1}f(x)dx<\epsilon$$